# Where could I find Rundeck SCM configuration?

Tags: rundeck

I have not fully configured SCM export plugin and saved the settings, thinking I will continue the configuration once I add ssh key to Rundeck storage. Unfortunately, Rundeck will now timeout when going to `JOBS` or `SETUP SCM...` pages. I tried using the API and it also times out when trying to get SCM plugin details.

Is there some file or table that contains the SCM export configuration that I could manually remove and start over with my configuration?

Error message:

```
[2021-08-01T01:00:00,000] ERROR services.ScmService - Unable to initialize SCM for project myproject for integration export
com.dtolabs.rundeck.plugins.scm.ScmPluginException: Failed fetch from the repository: git@domain:path/rundeck.git: Connection timed out (Connection timed out); java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor319.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to locate the configuration in the Rundeck database. After deleting the row, I am able to access SCM configuration again.

```
mysql> select name from storage limit 10;
+--------------------------+
| name                     |
+--------------------------+
| workflowConfigFix973     |
| project.properties       |
| project.properties       |
| user.aclpolicy.aclpolicy |
| scm-export.properties    |
+--------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from storage where name = 'scm-export.properties';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```